# MsgBox in Jquery, pass info to PHP and retrieve results

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, msgbox

As you can see i am noob at jquery / javascript, i need to pass variable to GET or POST written in form and the result from php need to be passed to jquery, i started to write smthing as below, but it doesnt work.

anyone help me out please

```
// id and settings for msg box

$("#registerin").click(function() {
  $.msgbox("<p>In order to process your request you must provide the following:</p>", {
    type    : "prompt",
    inputs  : [
      {type: "text",label: "Insert your Name:", value: "George", required: true},
    ],
    buttons : [
      {type: "submit", value: "OK"},
      {type: "cancel", value: "Exit"}
    ]
  }, // id and settings for msg box - end
   function(name) {
    // checking if name field has been set
    if(name) {
    // pass from field to php $_GET['name_php'] variable
      $.get("form.php", {name_php: name },
**// rewriten**
    function(data) {
    if (data){
        // inline the data creation/insertion
        $.msgbox($('#textbox').html(data), {type: "info"});
    } // if data end
  }); // function data end
**// rewriten**
    } // if name end
  }); // function name end

}); // registerin click
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.get` is an asynchronous function call, so that means that code below it is not garunteed to be run AFTER it has been proccessed. your callback function inside the `$.get` call should look like this:

```
function(data) {
    if (data){
        // inline the data creation/insertion
        $.msgbox($('#textbox').html(data), {type: "info"});
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple, i did rewrite, but msgbox does not initiate, what could be wrong ?